# Drag and Drop into different ListViews using QML (Kanban app)

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to create a Kanban view using QML.

Here's my code so far: https://gist.github.com/nuttyartist/66e628a53f014118055474b5823e5c4b

Everything seems to work fairly well, including dragging and dropping in the same ListView of tasks, but dragging and dropping into a different ListView of tasks doesn't work.
I want to recreate the same feelings of smooth drag and drop like I currently have with the same ListView.

[GIF of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJbGJ.gif)

I tried:

1. Inserting the model of the dropped task into the new ListView
2. Telling the delegate that it is being 'held' so it starts the drag on it and goes to the cursor location
3. Remove the previous item from the ListView

But it doesn't work and I'm kinda stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came up with a (sort of) hacky solution.

Whenever a task is entered into a task from a different ListView, I make the parent of the target's content bigger and push the content up or down (depending on the y axis, although the code there can be improved). While that happens I bind the target object to the dragged object so whenever the dragged object is released it will add its content to the different ListView at the right position. Then I remove the dragged object from the original ListView model.

Here's the full code:

`main.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: root
    width: 1200
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("TODOs")

    property int textAndTodosSpacing: 20
    property int todoColumnWidth: 250
    property int topAndBottomColumsMargins: 20

    Rectangle {
        id: appBackgroundContainer
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#0D1117"

        Row {
            spacing: textAndTodosSpacing

            Rectangle {
                id: textContainer
                width: 250
                height: 250
                color: "transparent"
                border.width: 1
                border.color: "black"
                y: (root.height / 2) - (height / 2)

                ScrollView {
                    width: parent.width
                    height: parent.height

                    TextArea {
                        width: parent.width
                        height: parent.height
                        color: "white"
                    }
                }

            }

            Item {
                id: todosContainer
                width: root.width - textContainer.width - textAndTodosSpacing - root.topAndBottomColumsMargins
                height: root.height
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: root.topAndBottomColumsMargins
                anchors.bottomMargin: root.topAndBottomColumsMargins

                DelegateModel {
                    id: visualModel
                    model: TodoColumnModel {}
                    delegate: TodoColumnDelegate {
                        todoColumnContentHeight: todosContainer.height - root.topAndBottomColumsMargins*3
                        rootContainer: todosContainer
                    }
                }

                ListView {
                    id: todosColumnsView
                    model: visualModel
                    anchors { fill: parent }
                    clip: true
                    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
                    spacing: 30
                    cacheBuffer: 20
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TodoColumnDelegate.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

MouseArea {
    id: dragArea

    property bool held: false
    property int todoColumnContentHeight: 300
    property var rootContainer

    anchors { top: parent.top; bottom: parent.bottom }
    width: todoColumnContent.width
    drag.target: held ? todoColumnContent : undefined
    drag.axis: Drag.XAxis
    onPressed: held = true
    onReleased: held = false

    Rectangle {
        id: todoColumnContent
        radius: 20
        width: 250
        height: dragArea.todoColumnContentHeight
        border.width: 1
        antialiasing: true
        border.color: Qt.rgba(33, 38, 45)
        color: "#010409"
        scale: dragArea.held ? 1.05 : 1.0
        anchors {
            id: todoColumnContentAnchors
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        Drag.active: dragArea.held
        Drag.source: dragArea
        Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
        Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2
        Drag.keys: "todoColumn"

        Behavior on scale {
            ScaleAnimator {
                duration: 300
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }

        //        // TODO: Mkae anchor animation work...
        //        // I think the solution is to call the transitions when held is false
        //        // And we need to change the parent as well?
        //        transitions: Transition {
        //            enabled: dragArea.held === false
        //            AnchorAnimation {
        //                duration: 300
        //                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
        //            }
        //        }

        states: [State {
                when: dragArea.held

                ParentChange { target: todoColumnContent; parent: dragArea.rootContainer}
                AnchorChanges {
                    target: todoColumnContent
                    anchors { horizontalCenter: undefined; verticalCenter: undefined }
                }
            }]

        Rectangle {
            id: numberOfTasksText
            x: columnName.x - 28
            y: columnName.y + columnName.height/2 - height/2
            width: 20
            height: 20
            radius: 20
            color: "#2d3139"

            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: "white"
                font.pointSize: 11
                text: "49"
            }
        }

        Text {
            id: columnName
            x: (todoColumnContent.width / 2) - (width / 2)
            y: 10
            text: model.title
            color: "white"
        }

        // Tasks

        Item {
            id: tasksContainer
            property int marginTop: 10
            width: todoColumnContent.width
            height: todoColumnContent.height - (columnName.y + columnName.height + marginTop * 2)
            y: columnName.y + columnName.height + marginTop

            DelegateModel {
                id: tasksVisualModel
                model: TodoTaskModel {}
                delegate: TodoTaskDelegate {
                    taskContentWidth: tasksContainer.width
                    rootContainer: dragArea.rootContainer
                    listViewParent: tasksView
                }
            }

            ListView {
                id: tasksView
                model: tasksVisualModel
                anchors { fill: parent }
                clip: true
                orientation: ListView.Vertical
                spacing: 10
                cacheBuffer: 50
            }
        }
    }

    DropArea {
        anchors { fill: parent}
        keys: ["todoColumn"]

        onEntered: (drag)=> {
                       visualModel.items.move(
                           drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex,
                           dragArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex)
                   }
    }
}
```

`TodoColumnModel.qml`

```
import QtQuick

ListModel {
    id: todoColumnModel

    ListElement {
        title: "TODO"
    }

    ListElement {
        title: "In Progress"
    }

    ListElement {
        title: "Done"
    }
}
```

`TodoTaskDelegate.qml`

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

MouseArea {
    id: taskDragArea

    property bool held: false
    property int taskContentWidth
    // TODO: replace var with proper types
    property var rootContainer
    property var listViewParent
    property int originalIndex: -1
    property var listViewModel: model
    property string taskText: model.taskText
    property int originalHeight

    property var targetDragged

    anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
    width: taskContent.width
    height: taskContent.height
    drag.target: held ? taskContent : undefined
    drag.axis: Drag.XAndYAxis

    onPressed: {
        held = true;
        originalIndex = DelegateModel.itemsIndex;
    }
    onReleased: {
        if(targetDragged) {
            targetDragged.listViewParent.model.items.insert(targetDragged.DelegateModel.itemsIndex, {taskText: model.taskText});
            listViewParent.model.items.remove(DelegateModel.itemsIndex);
        }

        held = false;
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        originalHeight = taskContent.height;
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: taskContent
        radius: 10
        width: taskDragArea.taskContentWidth -20
        height: 60
        border.width: 1
        antialiasing: true
        border.color: "#30363d"
        color: "#161b22"
        scale: taskDragArea.held ? 1.07 : 1.0

        anchors {
            id: taskContentAnchors
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
//            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        anchors.leftMargin: 5
        anchors.rightMargin: 5
        Drag.active: taskDragArea.held
        Drag.source: taskDragArea
        Drag.hotSpot.x: width / 2
        Drag.hotSpot.y: height / 2
        Drag.keys: "task"

        Behavior on scale {
            ScaleAnimator {
                duration: 300
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }

//        transitions: Transition {
//                AnchorAnimation { duration: 100 }
//            }


        states: [State {
                when: taskDragArea.held

                ParentChange { target: taskContent; parent: taskDragArea.rootContainer}
                AnchorChanges {
                    target: taskContent
                    anchors { top: undefined; horizontalCenter: undefined; verticalCenter: undefined }
                }
            }
        ]

        Text {
            id: taskTextDescription
            x: (taskContent.width / 2) - (width / 2)
            y: 10
            text: model.taskText
            color: "white"
        }
    }

    DropArea {
        id: dropArea
        anchors { fill: parent}
        keys: ["task"]

        onEntered: (drag)=> {
                       drag.source.targetDragged = taskDragArea
                       var sourceListView = drag.source.listViewParent;
                       var targetListView = taskDragArea.listViewParent;

                       if (sourceListView === targetListView) {
                           // Move the task within the same ListView
                           sourceListView.model.items.move(
                               drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex,
                               taskDragArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex
                               );
                       } else {
                           // Handle different ListView
                           taskDragArea.height = taskDragArea.originalHeight * 2 + taskDragArea.listViewParent.spacing;

                           if (drag.source.y > taskDragArea.y) {
                               taskContent.anchors.top = taskDragArea.top
                               taskContent.anchors.bottom = undefined
                           } else {
                               taskContent.anchors.top = undefined
                               taskContent.anchors.bottom = taskDragArea.bottom
                           }
                       }
                   }

        onExited: {
            drag.source.targetDragged = null;
            var sourceListView = drag.source.listViewParent;
            var targetListView = taskDragArea.listViewParent;

            if (sourceListView !== targetListView) {
                taskDragArea.height = taskDragArea.originalHeight;
                taskContent.anchors.top = undefined;
                taskContent.anchors.bottom = undefined;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`TodoTaskModel.qml`

```
import QtQuick

ListModel {
    id: todoTaskModel

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 1"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 2"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 3"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 4"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 5"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 6"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 7"
    }

    ListElement {
        taskText: "Task 8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a work in progress since there are multiple features that need to be implemented.

**One ListModel.**

In your example, you were heading towards implementing 3 ListModel, one for Todo, one for InProgress, and one for Done. I recommend you combine all your models together and have a taskType property that determines whether a task is "TODO", "In Progress" or "Done".

```
ListModel {
    id: tasks
}
Component.onCompleted: {
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        // let taskId = ...
        // let taskType = ...
        // let taskText = ... 
        tasks.append( { taskId, taskType, taskText } );
    }
}
```

**Configurable visual ListViews.**

We create 3 ListView instances all pointing to the same underlying tasks ListModel, e.g.

```
ListView {
    model: tasks
    //...
}
ListView {
    model: tasks
    //...
}
ListView {
    model: tasks
    //...
}
```

The instances differ because each ListView can implement a different filter so that reveal different records from the ListModel.

**The Drag/Drop UI/UX**

When the user begins dragging an item, we set the source items' Drag.active to true. For the destination, we watch the containsDrag property.

We make the UI/UX look good with color changes and z-order changes to give the user visibility of the item being dragged.

Also, when dragging from one ListView to another, it was necessary to set `clip: false` so that the dragged item isn't restricted to the bounds of the source ListView. When the dragging is complete, we restore `clip: true`.

**Updating ListModel/DelegateModel**

When the user completes the drag-drop operation we need to do the following:

1. Update the ListModel reflecting the change in taskType
2. Update the two DelegateModels to realize the taskType changed so it's removed from one visual model and added to the other
3. (Not implemented yet) Update the DelegateModel so that the task appears at the position index that the user intended

**Runnable Demo**

Here's a runnable demo of what's been implemented so far:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    id: main
    background: Rectangle { color: "black" }
    property int dragSource: -1
    property int dragTarget: -1
    RowLayout {
        width: parent.width
        height: 360
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: tasks
            clip: true
            headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
            header: TaskHeaderDelegate {
                text: "TODO"
                count: tasks.countByType("TODO")
            }
            delegate: TaskItemDelegate { visible: taskType === 'TODO' }
        }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            model: tasks
            clip: true
            headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
            header: TaskHeaderDelegate {
                text: "In Progress"
                count: tasks.countByType("In Progress")
            }
            delegate: TaskItemDelegate { visible: taskType === 'In Progress' }
        }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            clip: true
            model: tasks
            headerPositioning: ListView.OverlayHeader
            header: TaskHeaderDelegate {
                text: "Done"
                count: tasks.countByType("Done")
            }
            delegate: TaskItemDelegate { visible: taskType === 'Done' }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id: tasks
        function countByType(taskType) {
            let total = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < count; i++)
                if (get(i).taskType === taskType) ++total;
            return total;
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            let taskId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
            let taskType = ["TODO","In Progress","Done"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
            let taskText = "Task " + taskId;
            tasks.append({taskId,taskType,taskText});
        }
    }
    footer: Frame {
        Label {
            text: "Dragging: " + tasks.get(dragSource).taskText + " -> " + tasks.get(dragTarget).taskText
            color: "yellow"
            visible: dragSource !== -1 && dragTarget !== -1
        }
    }
}

// TaskItemDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Item {
    id: taskItem
    z: mouseArea.drag.active ? 2 : 0
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    property bool show: true
    width: listView.width
    height: visible ? 50 : 0
    DropArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        z: 2
        onContainsDragChanged: {
            dragTarget = containsDrag ? index : -1;
        }
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            border.color: parent.containsDrag ? "yellow" : "grey"
            color: "transparent"
            border.width: 1
            radius: 10
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        color: "#444"
        border.color: "white"
        radius: 10
        z: mouseArea.drag.active ? 2 : 0
        Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
        Label {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.margins: 10
            text: index
            color: "#666"
        }
        Label {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: taskText
            color: "white"
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
            onPressed: {
                dragSource = index;
                dragTarget = -1;
                listView.z = 2;
                listView.clip = false;
            }
            onReleased: {
                drag.target.x = 0;
                drag.target.y = 0;
                listView.z = 0
                listView.clip = true;
                if (dragSource !== -1 && dragTarget !== -1 && dragSource !== dragTarget) {
                    tasks.setProperty(dragSource, "taskType", tasks.get(dragTarget).taskType);
                    tasks.move(dragSource, dragTarget, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// TaskHeaderDelegate.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Rectangle {
    id: header
    property ListView listView: ListView.view
    width: listView.width
    height: 50
    color: "black"
    property string text: ""
    property int count: 0
    RowLayout {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        spacing: 20
        Label {
            text: header.count
            color: "white"
            background: Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: -radius
                radius: 5
                color: "#666"
            }
        }
        Label {
            text: header.text
            color: "white"
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Hey, Stephen! I like your work (and I've seen your many comments in QML issues here that helped quite a bit).

Your example doesn't provide an answer to my problem tho.

- First, dropping an item to a different ListView doesn't insert it there (what I needed help in).
- Secondly, I'm using quite a different structure than yours (described in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html) so it's a bit difficult to see what I can make of your code.
- Thirdly, I use one ListView for the Kanban boards and another one for the tasks inside the board delegate.

Comment: @Notes actually, your question is quite complex, I estimate it will take 3+ days to come up with a comprehensive answer, so, I can only do incremental updates to the answer when I am able. The structure of my answer and the Qt documentation is essentially the same. The devil is in the detail, hence, the degree of work to customize it to match your specification. It would actually help if you provided a reference to the word "Kanban" as I am unfamiliar with the term. BTW, I have pushed another update to the answer today. Unfortunately, the final edit is still missing.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your help. Your example doesn't work consistently. Many times it will not drop the item in the right place. But the main problem is that you're proposing a completely different architecture to my problem (sharing the same model, etc...), while I'm seeking a solution that works with my current architete.

Comment: I'm thinking that all I need to add inside the DropArea onEntered functions is:

// Insert the source's model into targetListView at the position
// Set drag.source.held = false to stop its dragging
// Make the delegate inserted into targetListView actively dragged at the cursor position
// Remove drag.source from sourceListView's model

Comment: I managed to get the effect I wanted by some hacking inside onEntered, but the onDropped signal isn't being called. https://gist.github.com/nuttyartist/a910f59e334ac944f99a413ef0783e02 Do you know why?