# Implementing drag-n-drop for tickets within and between categories in Kanban Board using QAbstractListModel and Qt 6.5.0

Tags: qt, listview, drag-and-drop, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I'm working on a training project that involves creating a **Kanban board**, and I'm having trouble implementing drag-n-drop for tickets both within and between categories.

In my current solution I use the *`CategoriesModel`* class, inherited from `QAbstractListModel`, which stores information about all categories in a particular project. It includes an object of class *`TicketsModel`* which also inherits from `QAbstractListModel` and is responsible for storing ticket information.

The problem is that I am not able to do the "correct" movement of the tickets within the model after visually dragging and dropping items within the `DelegateModel`.

In my current solution, I use the approach based on [example from Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-tutorials-dynamicview-dynamicview3-example.html), but it doesn't provide information about moving items between two different `ListView`. Here are the main parts of my code that are responsible for moving the tickets:

```cpp
void CategoriesModel::moveTicket(int fromCategory, int fromIndex, int toCategory, int toIndex)
{
    Ticket* tick = getTicketByIndex(fromCategory, fromIndex);
    m_categories.at(toCategory).getTickets()->insertTicketInto(tick, toIndex);
    removeTicketByIndex(fromCategory, fromIndex);

    QModelIndex fromModelIndex = createIndex(fromCategory, 0);
    QModelIndex toModelIndex   = createIndex(toCategory, 0);
    emit dataChanged(fromModelIndex, fromModelIndex);
    emit dataChanged(toModelIndex, toModelIndex);
}

void TicketsModel::moveTicketInternally(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
{
    // Invalid indexes
    if (fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex >= m_tickets.size() || toIndex < 0 || toIndex >= m_tickets.size()) { return; }

    // Start and end indexes are the same
    if (fromIndex == toIndex) { return; }

    Ticket* item = m_tickets.takeAt(fromIndex);
    insertTicketInto(item, toIndex);

    QModelIndex fromModelIndex = createIndex(fromIndex, 0);
    QModelIndex toModelIndex = createIndex(toIndex, 0);
    emit dataChanged(fromModelIndex, fromModelIndex);
    emit dataChanged(toModelIndex, toModelIndex);

}
```

Qml code responsible for the visualization of models:

```js
// Ticket displaying
Item
{
    MouseArea
    {
        id: mouseArea
        property bool held: false
        anchors.fill: parent

        drag.target: held ? ticketRect : undefined
        onPressAndHold: held = true
        onReleased: held = false

        DropArea
        {
            id: dropArea
            anchors.fill: parent

            property var fromIndex
            property var toIndex
            property var fromColumn
            property var toColumn

            onEntered: (drag) => {
                fromIndex = drag.source.DelegateModel.itemsIndex;
                toIndex = mouseArea.DelegateModel.itemsIndex;
                fromColumn = drag.source.DelegateModel.groups[1];
                toColumn = mouseArea.DelegateModel.groups[1];

                if (fromColumn !== toColumn) {
                    categoriesModel.moveTicket(categoriesModel.getCategoryIndexById(fromColumn), fromIndex, categoriesModel.getCategoryIndexById(toColumn), toIndex);
                } else {
                    visualModel.items.move(fromIndex, toIndex);
                    tickets.moveTicketInternally(fromIndex, toIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    …
    }
}

// Сategories displaying
Item
{
    id: category
    property string categoryId
    property alias tickets: visualModel.model

    Rectangle
    {
        anchors.fill: parent
            DelegateModel
            {
                id: visualModel
                groups: DelegateModelGroup {
                    name: category.categoryId
                    includeByDefault: true
                }
                delegate: ModelControlTicket { header: name }
            }

            ListView
            {
                id: ticketList
                model: visualModel
            }
    }
    …
}
```

The main ***disadvantages of my approach***, which are critical:

- There needs to be an asbtract "dummyTicket" that will zone the location to which the dragged ticket will move. When implementing it, there may be problems with data synchronization in the models.
- I use my own method *`moveTicketInternally`* to apply permutations from `DelegateModel` to C++ model, which in my mind is definitely not good practice.
- The current version of the solution may occasionally have an error `IndexOutOfRange` for property `fromCategory` which will cause the program to crash. Unfortunately, I didn't manage to find the reason for the array overrun.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how best to implement drag-n-drop functionality in this context, as well as advice on how to "properly" move tickets within a model after visually dragging and dropping items within a DelegateModel. Maybe the best solution in this scenario would be to use a completely different approach? If so, which one?

Comment: What is the reason you are using a DelegateModel? Since you already have the QAbstractListModel as base class, you can use these for the ListView, so I'm a bit confused about the DelegateModel. Removing that might possibly make it easier.

Comment: Because you're "goal" is to drag items between two ListView it creates a whole bunch of assumptions that may hinder your solution. For instance, what is your drop target? An item in a ListView? What if the target ListView has no items, you have nowhere to drop? Also, how is your data modeled? Do you have two models or is it one model and which ListView is a function of a ListElement within?

Comment: @Amfasis I use the `DelegateModel` as a proxy to maintain consistency of the element being manipulated with the mouse, even when the model changes. Without it, any modification in the model also leads to a change in the ticket that's currently held. Here are two GIFs for comparison: one with the `DelegateModel` *[link](https://imgur.com/o5XJFOe)*, and another without it *[link](https://imgur.com/3jGxTi9)*.

Comment: @StephenQuan The drop target is a `ListView` element. When confronted with a situation where the target `ListView` is devoid of items, one viable workaround is to append a *"dummyTicket"* to it. This adjustment allows for the seamless dragging of tickets between categories, although I acknowledge it might not be the optimal solution.

Comment: @StephenQuan As for data modeling, I have adopted a single model structure, where the model of tickets is embedded within the model of categories. The ultimate objective is to design a system akin to Github's solution as demonstrated in this *[gif link](https://imgur.com/VsK2uj0)*. More specifically, I aim to accurately represent the movement of a ticket for users across both the home category and other categories.

Comment: @NoName ah, now I see, you are using the onEntered handler to actually already move the item. That might not be the best idea. I think you should only show the highlighting line from the onEntered handler (and disable from onExited) and do the actual move in onDropped

Comment: The pain point is the `DelegateModel`. Because you have multiple delegate models, they have their each visual `DelegateModelGroup`. When an item jumps from one list to another, you have to notify remove the item from one `DelegateModelGroup` and paste it into the other `DelegateModelGroup`. Then, you have to update the visual position of the item within the target `DelegateModelGroup`. Sometime ago, I attempted to answer this question and decided it was simpler to just manage a single `ListModel` that is reused for multiple `ListView`. This also simplifies sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916045/drag-and-drop-into-different-listviews-using-qml-kanban-app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drag and Drop into different ListViews using QML (Kanban app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75916045/drag-and-drop-into-different-listviews-using-qml-kanban-app)